# split a word from string and save it in a variable

Tags: php, regex

I've a question.
I have a string, like this:
`hello, I am a string, -how are you?-`.

And I want to put any text in `- -` sign in another variable and remove it from original string (in short: cut it!).

How can I do it? I should do it with `preg_match` or `preg_split`?

If you help me, I will grateful to you!

Comment: By what criteria? Will there always be a `-xyz-` at the end of the string? Can there be multiple occurrences of the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really two separate operations, but you can use the same pattern for both

```
$str = "hello, I am a string, -how are you?-";
$pattern = "/-(.*?)-/";

if ( preg_match( $pattern, $str, $matches ) )
{
  $matched = $matches[1];
  $str = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $str );

  echo $matched, PHP_EOL, $str;
}
```

Note that this assumes that (and therefore only works when) only *one* section of text is demarcated by `-`

Answer (score 0):

A simple string split using `explode` (no regex needed) may help:

```
$s = 'hello, I am a string, -how are you?-';
$parts = explode('-', $s);
print_r($parts);

// Prints:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => hello, I am a string, 
//     [1] => how are you?
//     [2] => 
// )
```

You can also use `trim` functions to remove whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for is along the lines of:

```
preg_match("/\-[\d,\w,\s]+-/gi",'blah blah -hello world-',$myvar)
```

Now you can use `$myvar`. It'll return an array of results, so in this case you could use `$myvar[0]` and it'll return the first one `-hello world-`